# How to make jQuery function execute only once, even if we declare it multiple times in a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mongodb

I have a jQuery function when you click a button with particular class in a document, it will execute something. Ex. below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tambah', function(){
  alert('tombol tambah telah ditekan');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success tambah">+ tambah</button>
```

Lets say they are in the same script called 'script.php'. When I called the script once, the function of clicking that class will be executed once, but when I called the script again, when I clicked the button it executed twice. How to prevent it from executing more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling a function that performs the binding, then it can stack up.  In a case like this you would usually "unbind" first

```
$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '.tambah', function(){
  alert('tombol tambah telah ditekan');
});
```

Comment: on/off replaced bind/unbind. I'd also recommend maybe namespace-ing the handler. `$(document).off('click.someCustomNamespace').on('click.someCustomNamespace', () => {alert('...')})`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works for me. But unfortunately in my opinion the other answer is the most suitable, because it is function focused, not event focused.

Comment: The 'stopImmediatePropagation' solution is effectively a memory leak, a small one be it. Just attaching more and more event handlers as time goes on.

Comment: @AlienWithPizza that's pretty slick.  I wasn't aware we could name space events this way

Comment: actually as "best practise" I think your solution is way better than the stopImmediatePropagation I posted. But having many handler on the same event, shows that the whole script is already not perfect, so stopImmediatePropagation  is an easy solution. Beside it has the advantage of deciding within the eventhandler, whether you want the event to bubble or not... And as long as the eventhandlers arent attached by some kind of loop, memory shouldn't be such a big deal ;-)

Comment: @st'sahib hahah.. yeah, i think they both work good and the stopImmediatePropagation was better suited for OP's environment. I hope OP's binding function isn't executed 1000s of times during an application instance or that memory leak will get real

Comment: @AlienWithPizza can you explain more about memory leak or the link where I can read about it? I really want to know about that so my program can be optimized. Thank you.

Comment: @BonifaciusSarumpaet every event handler attached will take up some amount of memory. If you continue to call the script, handlers pile up, that memory will never be released. Depending on the number of times it is called, and how much memory each handler is holding onto, it will cause a larger leak. Not knowing the full context here we can't say but you probably won't ever have an issue with that. But it is simply not good practice, a band-aid solution. You should always clean up after yourself.

Comment: Oh yeah I get it. In this case the unbind() method is better because not only it answer my problems, also it cleans every declared event handler attached to the element. Thank you for the explanation, really appreciate it.
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/eradicating-memory-leaks-in-javascript/
Currently reading this for further info.
Also 1 more question, does unbind() only frees our element out of the event handler or does it also clears the event, preventing it for further use?

Answer (score 1):

`event.stopImmediatePropagation();` [[docs]](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) should do the trick

```js
$(document).on('click','.tambah',function(event){
    alert('tombol tambah telah ditekan');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$(document).on('click','.tambah',function(event){
    alert('tombol tambah telah ditekan');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success tambah">+ tambah</button>
```

Comment: While this does work, it is effectively a small memory leak. Actually it depends on what is done in the handler, it could end being a large one. Any variables used within the handler will be held around until the event is removed.